# Unity modify a value without creating temp variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a data class with the cameraPosition stored in it.

```
public Vector3 CameraPosition { get { return CameraTransform.position; } } // current position of the camera
```

In my controller class, I want to modify this

```
void Move() // move with the camera
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || data.MousePos.y >= Screen.height - data.BorderSize)
            data.CameraPosition.z += data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKey("s") || data.MousePos.y <= data.BorderSize)
            data.CameraPosition.z -= data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKey("d") || data.MousePos.x >= Screen.width - data.BorderSize)
            data.CameraPosition.x += data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKey("a") || data.MousePos.x <= data.BorderSize)
            data.CameraPosition.x -= data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void Scroll() // scroll the camera
    {
        data.CameraPosition.y -= data.ScrollInput * data.ScrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

So actually the compiler wants me to create temp variables. I can not modify `data.CameraPosition`.

Is there a way, to do this without temp variables?

Otherwise I would have to write

```
 private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 pos = data.CameraPosition;

        pos = Move(pos);
        pos = Scroll(pos);
        pos = LimitValues(pos);

        data.CameraPosition = pos;
    }

    Vector3 Move(Vector3 pos)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || data.MousePos.y >= Screen.height - data.BorderSize)
            pos.z += data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKey("s") || data.MousePos.y <= data.BorderSize)
            pos.z -= data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKey("d") || data.MousePos.x >= Screen.width - data.BorderSize)
            pos.x += data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKey("a") || data.MousePos.x <= data.BorderSize)
            pos.x -= data.MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        return pos;
    }

    Vector3 Scroll(Vector3 pos)
    {
        pos.y -= data.ScrollInput * data.ScrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        return pos;
    }

    Vector3 LimitValues(Vector3 pos)
    {
        pos.x = ClampMovement(data.CameraPosition.x, data.MapLimit.x);
        pos.y = ClampScroll(data.CameraPosition.y);
        pos.z = ClampMovement(data.CameraPosition.z, data.MapLimit.y);

        return pos;
    }
```

And I think, this looks really really bad.

Maybe someone knows a trick :)

Comment: Any particular reason you think this "looks really bad"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vector3` is a value type (struct). This means that your getter actually returns a copy of the struct, not a reference to it. You are correct in thinking that `data.CameraPosition.x` cannot be assigned to, because the property `data.CameraPosition` returns a copy of the value. Modifying this copy won't affect the original value (unless you assign it back at the end).

The only way to allow direct assignment of the fields of a `Vector3` would be to make it a public field (as opposed to a property). This is impossible in your example because your property refers to `CameraTransform.position` whish is not a field in your class.

By the way, in order to use `data.CameraPosition = pos;` you're going to need a setter that assigns the value: `set { CameraTransform.position = value; }`

Comment: Hm well I changed my property to `public Vector3 CameraPosition { get { return CameraTransform.position; } set { CameraTransform.position = value; } }` but it still can not be modified :/

Comment: You won't ever be able to _modify_ it directly, you'll only be able to assign a completely new value to it.